# css show image 20 px outside div

Tags: css

I have a question about css. How to show a div always 20px larger than parent element. So if I change the size the div should take 100% of the width and then 20px more on each side.

Comment: child element should be 20px `larger` than parent???

Answer (score 1):

You could make the child div `absolute`ly positioned to the parent (assuming it's `position: relative`)

You could then set the child to match the parent's width and height, then "stretch" it by adding padding and negative positioning values for compensation...

Please note the red square is the parent and the translucent overlay is the child.

```css
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  content: " ";
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note: I'm sure there's a much more elegant way of achieving this than what I've done but it seems to work in any case!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `calc()`:

```
width: calc(100% + 20px)
```

Plus 20px from each side:

```
height: calc(100% + 40px)
margin: -20px 0 0 -20px
width: calc(100% + 60px)
```

.. or

```
height: calc(100% + 40px)
transform: translate3d(-20px,-20px,0)
width: calc(100% + 60px)
```

Comment: calc does not support for all browsers

Answer (score 0):

why not do the other way around? The parent should be 20px bigger.

If you really need this, you can do something like this:

```css
.parent{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.parent .child{
    width:calc(100% + 40px);
    height:calc(100% + 40px);
    position:absolute;
    left:-20px;
    top:-20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    parent
    <div class="child">
        child
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with another solution with cal() function.

```
 Here is JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arifkarim/ohmfaj2d/
```